# Config quill in a nuxt project (VUE component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, quill

I want to delete the toolbar in quill but I cant.

I have the HTML:

```
<template>
    <quill v-model="content" :config="config"></quill>
</template
```

And inside script:

```
<script>
   import VueQuill from 'vue-quill';
   export default {
         data () {
            return {
                config: {
                    readOnly: true,
                    toolbar: false
                }
            }
        }
   }
</script>
```

Readonly is working, but toolbar is still displaying.

Comment: are you using any theme ?

Comment: I havent changed the theme, I think is using the default theme that it is "snow"

Comment: check i have answered, let me know its working or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set config like this

```
  <script>
       import VueQuill from 'vue-quill';
       export default {
             data () {
                return {
                    config: {
                        readOnly: true,
                        modules: {
                           toolbar: false
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    </script>
```

Also to remove toolbar div use CSS since currently there is no direct option available in the package/library you are using

```
<style scoped>
  .ql-toolbar { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: If I change 'toolbar: false' for 'toolbar:[]'. Buttons disappear, now I want to delete the div with the class ql-toolbar

Comment: I have deleted scoped and it works. With this, we dont need to add modules:{toolbar:[]}